# Accessing variables in Foreach -parrallel

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a straightforward task that I'd like to do concurrently.  I'd like a server to push out a file to a bunch of endpoints and then send a command.  The server is only coincidentally a server OS; I'm working with embedded devices and the server pushes information to them.  The endpoints are not Windows machines.

The manufacturer of the endpoints has a series of Power Shell modules to do what I want.  It can even do the task I want concurrently, however it's limited to 32 at a time.  I have over 100 endpoints.  The file I need to send is ~400mb, so it takes a while.  It takes longer for the endpoint to process the file than to send it.

I've come across several different technologies in Power Shell to allow for concurrency.  Jobs, runspaces, and worflows.  I started with workflows because they have `Foreach -Parrallel`, which seems really easy to wrap my head around.

However, it seems that it's difficult to get input into any of these concurrent methodologies, and also difficult to get output out.  My script is not currently working, and you can see the error below.  I'm thinking that there's some kind of syntax or reference error that I need to overcome.

```
$inputCSV = "$PSScriptRoot\Addresses.csv"
$ipaddressesCSV = import-csv $inputCSV | select-object "IPAddress"
Write-host "File imported"
Write-host $ipaddressesCSV



workflow pingparallel {
    param([string[]]$ipaddresses)

    ForEach -parallel($ip in $ipaddresses) {
        $remotehost = $ip.IPAddress
        if(Test-NetConnection $remotehost -InformationLevel quiet){
            Update-PUF -device $remotehost -path "C:\work\tsw-xx60_1.002.0016.001.puf" #-ShowProgress $true
            $workflow:workFlowArray += ($remotehost + " Success")
         }

        else {
            $workflow:workFlowArray +=($remotehost + " is in use.`n") 
         }   
     }
     $workFlowArray
     #$usedarray
 }



$workFlowArray=pingparallel  $ipaddressesCSV

Write-host "workFlowArray"
Write-host $workFlowArray
```

The output of the script:

```
PS <...>> C:\Work\workflowFWpufEDK.ps1
File imported
@{IPAddress=192.168.1.101} @{IPAddress=192.168.1.102} @{IPAddress=192.168.1.103}
Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Device' because it is null.
At pingparallel:14 char:14
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Device' because it is null.
At pingparallel:14 char:14
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Write-Error : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Device' because it is null.
At pingparallel:14 char:14
+ 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.RemoteException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

workFlowArray


PS C:\Users\Tablet>
```

The workflow is misnamed because I started with a [sample](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/21288b28-405d-4c7f-90fb-fbfd8a3d63a6/ping-script-help-using-foreach-parallel?forum=ITCG) called "pingparrallel" and have been trying to understand worflows.  The original script tried to use a particular ping class, and that didn't work.

How can I pass in the IP address of the device I want this 2nd party cmdlet to process correctly?

Does it matter that that 2nd party code is using runspaces?

Asking the manufacturer for assistance probably won't go so well.  It's a pet project of theirs, response times are slow for this technology, and I used to work there, so I have the inside scoop already.

Comment: try looking at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/06/20/parallel-processing-with-powershell/

Comment: Funny you should link to that article.  I found it shortly after posting this.  Haven't had time to digest it and see what applies yet, but it looks like the best explanation of workflows I've seen.

Comment: param([string[]]$ipaddresses) is called but $ipaddresses doesn't have any information in it. Earlier in your script, you are assigning $ipaddressesCSV as your variable. Is that the one you are wanting to use?

Comment: At first I had all the variables called `ipaddresses`.  While attempting to debug, I thought PowerShell might be getting confused with the same name inside and outside of the workflow, so I changed the variable name outside of the workflow.  There was no change in the scripts behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Named the Workflow as Flow, then within the workflow created the parallel foreach loop which tested the net connection status on true runs your command else fail,  Prefixed the variables in workflow with *$workflow:*

> created [PSCustomObjects]  from the workflow so they can be accessed from outside the workflow.

```
#Workflow
workflow Flow {

    param([string[]]$endpoints)

ForEach -parallel ( $endpoint in $endpoints) {

# Test-NetConnection
$workflow:Status = (Test-NetConnection $endpoint -InformationLevel quiet)

If ( $workflow:Status -eq "True") {

    Update-PUF -device $endpoint -path "C:\work\tsw-xx60_1.002.0016.001.puf"

    $workflow:StatusResult = "Success."}

Else {

    $workflow:StatusResult = "Fail."}

# Create PSObjects to access outside workflow
[PSCustomObject]$endpoint +"`t`t" + [PSCustomObject]$StatusResult

   }
}

#Import IPAddresses from CSV and add to endpoint array
$csv = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\Addresses.csv"
$endpoints = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach ($ip in $csv){  
    $Endpoints += $($ip.IPAddress)}


Flow -endpoint $endpoints
```